# App installed from android studio keeps crashing on my phone

Tags: java, android

ive just started with android developement and wondering why my app keeps crashing.... I'm trying to change activities as of now.....heres my code

```
package app.dm.com.tictac;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity{


    Button b;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),twoP.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

This is my XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#4285f4"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:text="TIC TAC TOE" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:text="Play 1v1"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The second class:

```
package app.dm.com.tictac;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by damian on 23/4/15.
 */
public class twoP extends MainActivity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.one_v);
        Button b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

And here is its XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout  
    xlmns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#4285f4"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">   

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Random BS "
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go Back"
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="98dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Once i install the app onto my device it just shows "Unfortunately ticTac has stopped". I really am not sure what my mistake is .Any help would be appreciated....Thank You

MY android manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="app.dm.com.tictac" >

     <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
     <activity
         android:name=".MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity android:name=".twoP">

    </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Hzti3K8FV7WTRlb0U1LTJyZVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Post the logcat output please. It will show the stack trace

Comment: First pb there is no button with id b1 in your first xml! With `android:layout_below="@+id/b1` you say to put this button below b1

Comment: what does the logcat stacktrace tell?

Comment: You didn't took a look at your own logcat... Do some research first

Comment: 04-23 19:57:43.033: E/AndroidRuntime(16703): Process: app.dm.com.tictac, PID: 16703
04-23 19:57:43.033: E/AndroidRuntime(16703): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.dm.com.tictac/app.dm.com.tictac.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
04-23 19:57:43.033: E/AndroidRuntime(16703):  at app.dm.com.tictac.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)

Comment: is there some error in  onclicklistener

Comment: ALSO


* What went wrong: Cannot read packageName from /home/damian/AndroidStudioProjects/ticTac/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml 


what do i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is -

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.dm.com.tictac/app.dm.com.tictac.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

It occurs at `app.dm.com.tictac.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)`

You are using
 `b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);` but you don't have a button with this id defined anywhere in any of the layout files. I think you meant to use in the layout file of the first activity.

Answer (score 0):

Try after replacing getApplicationContext() to MainActivity.this

And even after that the error not goes then please post the error logs here.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Cannot read packageName from /home/damian/AndroidStudioProjects/ticTac/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: what do i do to fix the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

In your first xml you have `android:layout_below="@+id/b1`. You probably meant to type`android:id="@+id/b2`

In your code, you call `b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);` however there is no Button with that id, therefor b is assigned `null`. Afterwards, you try to assign to that an `onClickListener` and the app crashes.

This is exactly what this line is telling you:

```
04-23 19:42:21.979: E/AndroidRuntime(13918): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.dm.com.tictac/app.dm.com.tictac.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```